# Please resolve this error ' initialization of ‘char’ from ‘char *’ makes integer from pointer without a cast ' 5 | char star = "*";

Tags: c

The code is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {  
    char star = "*";
      
    printf("This is %c",star);
      
    return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of `"*"` is a `char [2]` aka `char *` but you want a `char` which you write as:

```
char star = '*';
```